# generation of random multiset permutation with restrictions

Tags: permutation, combinatorics

Is there any known algorithm how to effectively generate any random multiset permutations with additional restrictions.

Example:
I have a multiset of items, for example: `{1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3}`, and a restricting set of sets, for example {`{3}`,`{1,2}`,`{1,2,3}`,`{1,2,3}`,`{1,2,3}`,`{1,2,3}`,`{2,3}`,`{2,3}`}. I am looking for permutations of items, but the first element must be 3, and the second must be 1 or 2, etc.

One such permutation that fits restrictions is: `{3,1,1,1,2,2,3,3}`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is. I asked in [this German forum](http://matheplanet.com/index.html) and got the following answer: The problem can be reduced to finding [a maximum matching on a bipartite graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29#Maximum_matchings_in_bipartite_graphs).
In order to do this, introduce vertices for all elements in the multiset. These vertices form the one side of the bipartite graph. Then, introduce vertices fo each restriction set. These vertices form the other side of the bipartite graph. Now introduce edges from each restriction set to those vertices on the first side, such that the vertex on the first side is "hit" if and only if it represents an element that is contained in the connected set.

The bipartite graph for your example would look like this:
[image]

Now the matching chooses edges in a way that no two adjacent edges are chosen. E.g. the first "1" is chosen for the second restriction "{1,2}", then it can not be used for any other restriction any more, since the use of another edge from this vertex would not result in a matching any more.

Feel free to ask in case you got another question on this.